# Django JSONField

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

We have been using JSONField from [`jsonfield`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield) library for a while, but now we want to use native [PostgreSQL JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). So I would like to know whether it is possible to change field types for existing models preserving old field names and without loosing any data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

1. Keep the existing `jsonfield` and add the new `PostreSQL JSONField`.
2. Generate a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), which iterates through each record migrating the data from the old field to the new one.
3. Once you've run the migration you can deprecate the old field and remove it without any data loss.

### References

[Django Data Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change fields' types and names without loosing the data.
You just need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` every time you change something`in your models.py

Comment: When you change a name or type, there is a possibility for data loss if one or both cases are true:

1. Django is unable to determine if you meant to add a new field and remove the old one.

2. Django does not know how to convert one type to another. (i.e.: `string` to `int`).

Comment: 1. that's why when there's a confusion, django asks (when running `makemigrations`)  and you have to answer with Yes/No , in case he didn't get what you mean, you can always edit the migration file 2. in that case, there will be probably errors, but no data loss